# Where should I retrieve the ChannelHandlerContext for later use on opened connections in Netty?

Tags: netty

The [documentation of the `ChannelHandlerContext`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html) explains, that a `ChannelHandlerContext` can be retrieved for later use. I’m implementing a gossip-based membership protocol using Netty. Every running system can accept and create connections. There is a `Peer` class with an instance for every connected peer. This peer class has an attribute for the context, to allow sending messages through its instances. Keeping the `ChannelHandlerContext` when dealing with a server connection, was straight-forward in my case, but I’m not sure where or when this retrieving should happen when opening a connection. Is there a recommended way, to retrieve and keep the `ChannelHandlerContext`?

In my project I’m using a `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` that only adds the context handler and removes itself from the pipeline:

```java
class PeerContextRetriever extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    private final Peer peer;

    PeerContextActivator(Peer peer) {
        this.peer = peer;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SocketAddress remoteAddress, SocketAddress localAddress, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        promise.addListener(future -> peer.setContext(ctx));
        promise.addListener(future -> ctx.channel().pipeline().remove(this));
        super.connect(ctx, remoteAddress, localAddress, promise);
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to do it or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handlerAdded(...)` is a good place. You can override this in your `ChannelHandler`. At the end it not really matters much but `handlerAdded` is the first that is called

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Norman. I applied your suggestion because just based on the name, it hints at this purpose. Also, adding this very early is what I intended.